# Javascript Errors in IE11 Object doesn't support this action & Expected identifier

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, jquery-select2

I have a website that has 2 errors in IE11. My select2 and Google Maps are not working correctly. I looked at the code where the errors are but did not find anything unusual.

**The errors are:**

```
SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
app.js (27,2)

SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action
main.js (37,5)
```

**app.js:**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'owl',
    'select2',
    'scrollto',
    'header',
    'productfinderform',
    'productdetail',
    'procomponents',
    'authorizedcenters',
    'compinquiryform',
    'imageslidermodule',
    'dealerinquiry',
], function(
    $,
    Owl,
    Select2,
    ScrollTo,
    Header,
    ProductFinderForm,
    ProductDetail,
    ProComponents,
    AuthorizedCenters,
    ComponentsInquiryForm,
    ImageSliderModule,
    DealerInquiry,
    ){                           <-- this is line 27
```

**main.js:**

```
require([ 'app'], function(App) {
    'use strict';
    var app = new App();           <-- this is line 37
});
```

the website is based on WordPress.
link to the website [www.wp-suspenion.com](https://www,wp-suspension.com)

Any suggestion, idea, solution?

Thanks

Comment: For the identifier error, I could see that the function parameters has one extra comma (, ) at the end of last parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your app.js file, at line 26, you have a comma after DealerInquiry which is making your code to expect another param after it. This is what is producing the first error.

The second error is probably caused because what you are passing into the object "App" is something that cannot be instantiated through new. If you are passing already an instance of an object you don't need to create it through new, and if it's a function you can execute it directly with App(); without using new.

Comment: thanks, just removing the comma removed the 2nd error as well.

select2 and google maps still not working, but at least I got rid of that errors